# Stop forwarding page to servlet when clicking no on javascript confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets

I have created a link which is sending a request for deletion of record in servlet. I am trying to ask a confirmation message before deleting the record on the same page with the help of javascript. The problem is that whether I click on yes or no its deleting the record. Should I need to do some modification in servlet or in the javascript so that the request will not forward to servlet if the user clicks no and page the will remain as it is?

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function getConfirmation() {
    var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
    if (retVal == true) {

        return true;
    } else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<td>
    <div align="center">
        <a href="DeleteController?op=2&from=allResult&id=<%=one.getId()%>" onclick="getConfirmation();">
          Delete
        </a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your anchor, change onclick to `onclick="return getConfirmation();"`

```
<a onclick="return getConfirmation();" href="DeleteController?op=2&from=allResult&id=<%=one.getId()%>">Delete</a>
```

---

And just return the function `confirm()`. It will return `true` on `OK` and default action will occur; on `Cancel` it will return `false` and prevent action.

```
function getConfirmation(){
   return confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kcsk4aw4/)**

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
onclick="return getConfirmation();"
```

in your html:

```
<td>
    <div align="center"><a href="DeleteController?op=2&from=allResult&id=<%=one.getId()%>" onclick="return getConfirmation();">Delete</a></div>
</td>
```

If you want to prevent redirection on any button `click` of confirm box, you should always `return false` from the function.

```
function getConfirmation() {
    var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
    if (retVal) {
        // Ok, do some processing here
        // Your code here
    }

    // To prevent redirection
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think all he wants to do is to stop the browser from following the link in case the user cancels the confirmation dialog, in which case the following would work fine `function getConfirmation() { return confirm("Do you want to continue?"); }`

Answer (score 0):

You could load your URL in your javascript using [assign](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_assign.asp). One of the patterns that I've found useful, is in jQuery document.ready, you can find all tags of a certain kind (in this case "a" link tags), assign them ids from an iterator, save the actual URL in a JSON, and remove it from the actual link. That way, you can handle everything from Javascript